# WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync returns callback url only

Tags: azure, windows-8, acs

I have a simple web API app which should be called from a metro app.
I am using WebAuthenticationBroker  to get the authentication token.

```
var ipUri = new Uri("https://xxx.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fyyy:2858%2f");

var callbackUri = new Uri(http://yyy:2858/);

WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                       WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                       ipUri,callbackUri);

if (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
{
     tokenBlock.Text = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that in webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData I get only the application callback url (i.e. ) and not the token.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Manu

Comment: I'm connecting to facebook, the responseData return the callback uri with the token at the end... are you sure that your broker are sending the token at the url?